# Why is CompassionPit.com's homepage breaking in IE6, but working great in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have no idea what's going on!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CompassionPit's Homepage utilizes *transparent PNG's*.

IE6 doesn't support this transparency and displays the 'transparent' part as a light gray color. Support for PNG transparency was added in IE7+.

UPDATE: As to the buttons dropping to the bottom of the page, it appears the iframe is the culprit. It's width is too big for the space it's containing div is supposed to take up, and IE6 is just automatically dropping it down.

Comment: very helpful, thanks. the other issue is that the "Listen" and "Vent" button-links are getting booted to the bottom of the page. See: https://img.skitch.com/20110524-pshujbkmiryiwd1chf8bi8y3ke.gif

Comment: @Zachary np. don't forget to mark as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Well, my main question was about the attached screenshot... It's why I tagged "CSS"...

Comment: @Zachary ah, okay. checking it.